# How can I remove #N/A in a formula string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have

- excelfiles with in first colomn the subject nameand in the n-the column a variable i'm interested in from that ID.
- I have several such files with different subject names (but from the same pool)
- Every excelfile is the same test done under a new condition
- for every ID i have figures saved in a map.

I wanted to obtain the following:

- making a new file where

  - the first column are all my ID's from my masterpool
  - every file/sheet stands for one n variable. Every column is the value of that variable under the condition defined by the column. (so kinda like a switch)
  - not every cell has a value, some are empty
  - If a cell has a value, I want to make it a hyperlink and link it to a figure

Everything worked except for one thing: I can't leave empty cells blank.

Here I have written two formula's in Excel that do what I want to but still give me a #N/A or #NAME if cells are empty

Can anyone give me some pointers?

```
=if(vlookup($A3;'C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\THE END\Resultaten\[Model btt.xls]0 female'!$A$1:$O$65536;8;false); HYPERLINK(concatenate ("C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\THE END\Figuren\Model btt_ Minimum age 0_ Gender female_ File ";A3;".tif");vlookup($A3;'C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\THE END\Resultaten\[Model btt.xls]0 female'!$A$1:$O$65536;8;false));””)



=if.error(HYPERLINK(concatenate("C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\THE END\Figuren\Model btt_ Minimum age 0_ Gender female_ File ";A3;".tif");vlookup($A3;'C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\THE END\Resultaten\[Model btt.xls]0 female'!$A$1:$O$65536;8;false));””)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your equation in IfError, e.g.

```
=IFERROR(YourEquation,"")
```

Whatever you put in place of the "" is what will be placed in the cell if the formula evaluates to an error.  In this case it would appear as a blank cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 2003 and below you can try this. =IF(ISNA(YourEquation)," ",YourEquation)